# Windb getting .dmp file to work

Tags: dll, windbg, debug-symbols

I have a program that uses different dlls and it crashed.
I am trying to work out the cause of the crash using WinDbg but I am having no luck so far.

I have the .dmp file but I have tried addig that as the symbol path, I have tried adding the dlls in th symbol path also and a few other things but it keeps telling me it could not find myprogram.dmp/symbols etc or just that the symbols could not be found.

What is the right method to get it working with the .dmp file?

Thanks I am new to this and finding online documentation only seems to help for programs that don`t have DLLs and other non built-in DLLs.

Example of some of the errors:

> *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for mydll.dll
>
> *** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for myprogram.dll
>
> PDB not found : c:\users\me\desktop\myprogram.dmp\symbols\dll\ole32.pdb

I managed to load the default windows symbols adding the downloaded symbols to the symbols path. Must I add DLLs I am using in my project to the symbols folder or something?

> PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  WRONG_SYMBOLS
>
> C:\Users\me\Desktop\Assignments\4. DPI-600 Testing\DumpFileDebugging\symbols

Answer (score 1):

First, set up a path for your private symbols. Let's call it X:\mysymbols. Copy all PDBs into that folder, just as a flat list. In WinDbg, set the symbol path to that folder

```
.sympath X:\mysymbols
```

Next, let WinDbg find the Microsoft stuff. Create a folder X:\microsymbols. Put nothing inside and do not use the same folder as X:\mysymbols. Add that folder to the symbol path:

```
.symfix+ X:\microsymbols
```

Now that everything is set up correctly, tell the debugger to refresh:

```
.reload
```

In rare cases only a

```
.reload /f; ld *
```

helps.

If you're still unlucky, try

```
!sym noisy
```

so that the debugger tells you what exactly is wrong with the symbols. Look up the error messages and try to fix them.

If it still goes wrong, you might simply not have the correct PDBs. PDBs are correlated to modules (DLLs and EXEs) by a kind of hash / timestamp. So either get the correct PDBs or try

```
.symopt+ 0x40
```

which forces the debugger to load whatever he gets without checking the hash. Be aware that callstacks etc. may be misleading if they are too far off.

Comment: Hey Thomas, I have done what you said and the microsoft symbols seem to work its just I need the symbols for our .exe The error is: *** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for myProgram.GUI.exe   In the\mysymbols I have put the .dmp file, do I need to add any other files, dlls maybe?

Comment: @user3774466: Could you add the output of `!sym noisy;.reload` to your question?